# Binding prefix key in tmux twice really needed?

Tags: configuration, tmux

In various blogs explaining the terminal multiplexer `tmux` and Git repositories containing a configuration file `tmux.conf` I find the following two lines (possibly with a varying prefix key):

```
set -g prefix2 C-a
bind C-a send-prefix -2
```

But what I couldn't find an answer for is why the second line is needed. As to my understanding the first line already binds the given key as the secondary prefix. I also tried to configure `tmux` with only the first line present and it seems to work. So why should it be bound a second time to explicitly send the secondary prefix key again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second line means <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> sends a literal Ctrl-A input to the program ([`send-prefix`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#send-prefix)). If you don't have a use for that, you don't need it, though it also doesn't hurt. It isn't binding the key a second time.

One use case for this is running `tmux` or `screen` inside tmux.

Comment: Since I mapped my secondary prefix key to `C-s` and disabled software flow control with `Ctrl-S`/`Ctrl-Q` in my Bash shell I should be able to hit `Ctrl-A` to move to the beginning of a command line. Isn't nesting of `tmux`  advised against?

Comment: If bash is in emacs mode and Ctrl-A isn't bound to anything else, yes.

Comment: "Advised against" doesn't mean nobody does it, by choice or otherwise. I wouldn't set it up as a long-term workflow personally.